# wxPython: Dynamically drawn picture becomes broken

Tags: wxpython

I'm learning wxPython and faced the following glitch in the tutorial example.

After the application is started it shows the drawing with sizes based on the application window's sizes. And in the very beginning it looks as it should be. But when I'm resizing the window the drawing becomes broken. Here is the video http://screencast.com/t/0XOetqJ2W5x

And here is the code:

```
# Chapter 8: Drawing to the Screen, Using Device Contexts
# Recipe 1: Screen Drawing
#
import os
import wx

#---- Recipe Code ----#

class Smiley(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=(50,50)):
        super(Smiley, self).__init__(parent,
                                     size=size,
                                     style=wx.NO_BORDER)

        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        """Draw the image on to the panel"""
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self) # Must create a PaintDC

        # Get the working rectangle we can draw in
        rect = self.GetClientRect()

        # Setup the DC
        dc.SetPen(wx.BLACK_PEN) # for drawing lines / borders
        yellowbrush = wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255, 255, 0))
        dc.SetBrush(yellowbrush) # Yellow fill

        # Find the center and draw the circle
        cx = (rect.width / 2) + rect.x
        cy = (rect.width / 2) + rect.y
        radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        dc.DrawCircle(cx, cy, radius)

        # Give it some square blue eyes
        # Calc the size of the eyes 1/8th total
        eyesz = (rect.width / 8, rect.height / 8)
        eyepos = (cx / 2, cy / 2)
        dc.SetBrush(wx.BLUE_BRUSH)
        dc.DrawRectangle(eyepos[0], eyepos[1],
                         eyesz[0], eyesz[1])
        eyepos = (eyepos[0] + (cx - eyesz[0]), eyepos[1])
        dc.DrawRectangle(eyepos[0], eyepos[1],
                         eyesz[0], eyesz[1])

        # Draw the smile
        dc.SetBrush(yellowbrush)
        startpos = (cx / 2, (cy / 2) + cy)
        endpos = (cx + startpos[0], startpos[1])
        dc.DrawArc(startpos[0], startpos[1],
                   endpos[0], endpos[1], cx, cy)

        # Draw a yellow rectangle to cover up the
        # unwanted black lines from the wedge part of
        # our arc
        dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
        dc.DrawRectangle(startpos[0], cy,
                         endpos[0] - startpos[0],
                         startpos[1] - cy)

#---- End Recipe Code ----#

class SmileyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = SmileyFrame(None,
                                 title="Drawing Shapes",
                                 size=(300,400))
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

class SmileyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = SmileyPanel(self)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class SmileyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Layout
        self.__DoLayout()

    def __DoLayout(self):
        # Layout a grid of 4 smileys
        msizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 0, 0)

        for x in range(4):
            smile = Smiley(self)
            msizer.Add(smile, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(msizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SmileyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

As you can see the drawing funstions are placed in the OnPaint method which is binded to the wx.EVT_PAINT event. So I thought it should draw a new image on the panel every time the window is re-painted by the system.

I'm using Win7, Python2.7 and wxPython 2.8.12.1

This is important for me as I'm going to write an aplication with scalable diagrams on its window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution - I have to use wx.BufferedDC and wx.EmptyBitmap. I found it in 'wxPython in Action' book (the example about the Sketch app).

Here is a new code:

```
import wx


class Smiley(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, size=(50,50)):
        super(Smiley, self).__init__(parent,
                                     size=size,
                                     style=wx.NO_BORDER)

        self.InitBuffer()                   # new
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize) # new
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_IDLE, self.OnIdle) # new

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

# new block
    def InitBuffer(self):
        self.client_size = self.GetClientSize()
        self.buffer = wx.EmptyBitmap(self.client_size.width, self.client_size.height)
        dc = wx.BufferedDC(None, self.buffer)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour()))
        dc.Clear()
        self.DrawImage(dc)
        self.reInitBuffer = False

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.reInitBuffer = True

    def OnIdle(self, event):
        if self.reInitBuffer:
            self.InitBuffer()
            self.Refresh(False)

    def DrawImage(self, dc):

        # Get the working rectangle we can draw in
        rect = self.client_size 

        # Find a square inside a rectangle (size of the client)
        min_side = min(rect.x, rect.y)
        rect.SetHeight(min_side)
        rect.SetWidth(min_side)

        # Setup the DC
        dc.SetPen(wx.BLACK_PEN) # for drawing lines / borders
        yellowbrush = wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255, 255, 0))
        dc.SetBrush(yellowbrush) # Yellow fill

        # Find the center and draw the circle
        cx = rect.width / 2
        cy = rect.width / 2
        radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        dc.DrawCircle(cx, cy, radius)

        # Give it some square blue eyes
        # Calc the size of the eyes 1/8th total
        eyesz = (rect.width / 8, rect.height / 8)
        eyepos = (cx / 2, cy / 2)
        dc.SetBrush(wx.BLUE_BRUSH)
        dc.DrawRectangle(eyepos[0], eyepos[1],
                         eyesz[0], eyesz[1])
        eyepos = (eyepos[0] + (cx - eyesz[0]), eyepos[1])
        dc.DrawRectangle(eyepos[0], eyepos[1],
                         eyesz[0], eyesz[1])

        # Draw the smile
        dc.SetBrush(yellowbrush)
        startpos = (cx / 2, (cy / 2) + cy)
        endpos = (cx + startpos[0], startpos[1])
        dc.DrawArc(startpos[0], startpos[1],
                   endpos[0], endpos[1], cx, cy)

        # Draw a yellow rectangle to cover up the
        # unwanted black lines from the wedge part of
        # our arc
        dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
        dc.DrawRectangle(startpos[0], cy,
                         endpos[0] - startpos[0],
                         startpos[1] - cy)
# end of a new block

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer)


class SmileyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = SmileyFrame(None,
                                 title="Drawing Shapes",
                                 size=(300,400))
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

class SmileyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = SmileyPanel(self)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class SmileyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Layout
        self.__DoLayout()

    def __DoLayout(self):
        # Layout a grid of 4 smileys
        msizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 0, 0)

        for x in range(4):
            smile = Smiley(self)
            msizer.Add(smile, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(msizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SmileyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

And here how it works now: http://screencast.com/t/HXohd4tVJi

Not perfect, but much better.
I hope I'll find the way to make it work more close to be perfect

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something completely different, but I've been drawing in wx.Python all day, so I saw the answer here pretty quickly -- just call `self.InitBuffer()` every time the window resizes.

just add `self.InitBuffer()` to line 28 of your mostly fixed code, it makes it work perfectly for me.

```
def OnSize(self, event):
    self.reInitBuffer = True
    self.InitBuffer()
```